# Sphere and cubic Bézier curve intersection points

Tags: geometry, parametric, spheres, bezier-curve, programming

I am trying to find a sphere and a cubic Bézier curve intersection points.

Sphere:
$$
\begin{align} x &= x_0 + r \sin \theta  \; \cos\varphi \\
y &= y_0 + r \sin  \theta \; \sin\varphi \qquad (0 \leq  \theta \leq \pi,\;  0 \leq \varphi < 2\pi ) \\
z &= z_0 + r \cos \theta \,\end{align}
$$

May be just:
$$
\begin{align} x &= r \sin \theta  \; \cos\varphi \\
y &= r \sin  \theta \; \sin\varphi \\
z &= r \cos \theta \,\end{align}
$$

Bézier curve:
$$
\mathbf{B}(t) = (1-t)^3\mathbf{P}_0+3(1-t)^2t\mathbf{P}_1+3(1-t)t^2\mathbf{P}_2+t^3\mathbf{P}_3,\ 0 \le t \le 1
$$

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1975016/482876) the answerer gave the formula:
$$
\mathbf{B}(t) \cdot \mathbf{B}(t) = r^2
$$

He says, this is «equation of degree 6», but I don't get why. It seems the cosine of the vector dot product must equal to 1, so it must be just:
$$
\mathbf{B}(t) = r
$$

If not, then why? And, if I mistake, how to solve this?

**Edit**:

Well, it's actually:
$$
\| \mathbf B (t) \| = r
$$

Comment: A scalar product of a vector with itself is a number, so comparing it to $r^2$ is OK. But a vector itself can not be compared to a scalar $r$. However, you may say $\left\vert \mathbf{B}(t) \right\vert = r$ instead.

Comment: Please see the comments I made following my answer to the other question. I said essentially the same thing as @CiaPan.

Comment: Also, it’s easy to draw a cubic Bézier curve that intersects a sphere in 6 places, so whatever equation you choose to solve must have (at least) 6 roots.